# Paste images from MS Word to contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, contenteditable

I've created a text editor, using a contenteditable div. The user can copy and paste text from word to the website. Only the images aren't working, because the src points to a local path.

I think I should encode the image to base64, before it is displayed, but the problem is, that the images cant be displayed, because they are local files.

Answer (score -3):

Try using some remote server to hold the photos so that they can be utilized. Try something like picpaste.com, however they only hold files temporarily I presume.